# Magento Cron Job unexpected behavior

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

I am working on a custom Magento module and set up a Cron job for it.
Every thing is working fine but i am worried about the unexpected behavior of Cron job ( Random number of execution ). 
When i execute cron.php manually it calls the observer's method of my module more then 1 times (Number of execution is not fixed, some times 3 some time 5 etc).
I just want to execute observer's method only once.
Here is my code.

**1) Daffodil/Birthdaywish/etc/config.xml**

```
...
 ...
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <daffodil_birthdaywish>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>birthdaywish/observe::sendBirthdayMail</model>
                </run>
            </daffodil_birthdaywish>
        </jobs>
 </crontab>
 ...
```

**2) Daffodil/Birthdaywish/Model/observe.php**

```
Class Daffodil_Birthdaywish_Model_Observe {

    public function sendBirthdayMail() {

         echo "<h1>Hello</h1>";

    }

}
```

If i execute cron.php the expected output should be 
**Hello** 
But the current output is some time 
**Hello  Hello Hello** 
 and some time
**Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello**

I just want to know why the observer's method is executing number of times (Random number of times) ? 
Is there any way to change the status of scheduled cron as "COMPLETE" so it will not execute twice ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is because of your cron schedule:

```
    <schedule>
        <cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr>
    </schedule>
```

You specify that the cron should run all the time. Magento's cron.php simply collects all information from all the cron jobs and schedules them in the cron_schedule table in your Magento database.

The cron.php should be called all the time and it manages all other cronjobs.

Thus, for example if you set your cronjob to run once an hour and regularly call the cron.php then it will only run once per hour.

You would do that like this:

```
    <schedule>
        <cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
    </schedule>
```

so it runs every hour at 0 minutes (5 o'clock, 6 o'clock etc).

Also have a look here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: I think this solution will works. because when your cron expression is <cron_expr>* * * * * *</cron_expr> it means will run every second. and it depends on your server running.